# JavaFX ComboBox search

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I'm trying to sort in a JavaFX `ComboBox`, but when I press the spacebar, an error occurs. I can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

Minimal example:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

public class TestFX extends Application {

    private ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        cb.setEditable(true);

        FlowPane root = new FlowPane(cb);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Sort ComboBox");
        stage.show();

        fillComboBox();
    }

    public void fillComboBox() {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();

        al.add("Benedict Cumberbatch");
        al.add("Elizabeth Olsen");
        al.add("Xochitl Gomez");
        al.add("Benedict Wong");
        al.add("Rachel McAdams");
        al.add("Chiwetel Ejiofor");

        String[] lfmc = new String[al.size()];
        lfmc = al.toArray(lfmc);

        cb.getItems().addAll(lfmc);
        FilteredList<String> filtered = new FilteredList<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(al), b -> true);
        cb.getEditor().textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                System.out.println(newValue);
                filtered.setPredicate(person -> {
                    String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
                    if (person.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) != -1)
                        return true;
                    return false;
                });
                System.out.println(filtered);

                cb.getItems().clear();
                String[] lfmcEnd = new String[filtered.size()];
                lfmcEnd = filtered.toArray(lfmcEnd);
                cb.getItems().addAll(lfmcEnd);
                cb.show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.getText(TextInputControl.java:459)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.updateContent(TextInputControl.java:573)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(TextInputControl.java:564)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin.replaceText(TextFieldSkin.java:447)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.replaceText(TextFieldBehavior.java:186)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.defaultKeyTyped(TextInputControlBehavior.java:414)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.lambda$keyMapping$62(TextInputControlBehavior.java:344)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8797)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.lambda$new$3(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:167)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventFilterRecord.handleCapturingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:321)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchCapturingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:98)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchCapturingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:221)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchCapturingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:180)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchCapturingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:43)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:52)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:4089)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2146)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2614)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:218)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:150)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:249)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:542)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Provide the stack trace in the question, formatted as code.

Comment: Provide a [mcve], no fxml, no database,just hardcoded data.  Make it replicable by copy and paste with no change or addition.

Comment: @jewelsea i did it.

Comment: Do you really need to be jumping around so much between all these different arrays and lists? Typically you create an underlying list and a filtered list wrapping it, and then set the filtered list to be the items list for the control (e.g. the combo box).

Comment: @James_D   if I remove the first array, the error remains, but initially the combobox is not full.

Comment: The basic problem with this approach is that changing the items list will, under some circumstances, change the text in the editor, which in turn changes the items list (by your listener). So either you can see inconsistent state (which is what you're observing, where the control gets confused about how many items are in the list), or you end up with infinite recursion (which would happen if you do the more intuitive thing and set the items to the filtered list).

Comment: [ControlsFX](https://controlsfx.github.io/) has a [`SearchableComboBox`](https://controlsfx.github.io/javadoc/11.1.1/org.controlsfx.controls/org/controlsfx/control/SearchableComboBox.html). The implementation used there is to place a separate search field on top of the combo box when the combo is showing, and update the items list when it changes. (This is all done in the [skin implementation](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/master/controlsfx/src/main/java/impl/org/controlsfx/skin/SearchableComboBoxSkin.java).)

Comment: @Danilov.nikolay.a I formatted your example to make it easier to read (simply copy-pasted into an IDE and used the auto-formatter, and then copy-pasted back to question) with no other changes (except for adding a couple `<>` to get rid of raw types warnings). I also added the stack trace I got (after pressing the spacebar _twice_) when running your example. Let me know if I accidently broke something or if your error looks significantly different.

Comment: I would use `SearchableComboBox` from _ControlsFX_, as mentioned by @James_D. I managed to fix your code so that the error you're currently seeing no longer happens. However, various actions now seem to cause a `StackOverflowError`, which I currently don't know how to fix. Using a known, working implementation (`SearchableComboBox`) will likely save you much time and effort compared to trying to "reinvent the wheel".

Comment: Thanks. I will try use SearchableComboBox. Thanks again.

Comment: I thought it would be possible to do it without a ControlsFX. I thought I'd solve the problem. But...

Comment: If you do want to do this without ControlsFX, the basic strategy they use (place a separate text field over the top of the combo box when the combo box is showing) and then binding between the two is probably the easiest approach. You wouldn't necessarily have to go to the trouble of writing a skin (just put the two in a stack pane, perhaps?). But, if someone with a whole team behind them has already done the work...

Comment: "_I thought I'd solve the problem. But..._" – But... what? Note if you're getting module/access errors, then check out https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/wiki/Using-ControlsFX-with-JDK-9-and-above